# Android - using the same variable value between if else statement

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first android app here, and I'd stumbled upon a problem where I need to use the value of a variable between an if-else statement.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int guess, x, y;
    String st_bot, st_top;

    if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_guess){

        st_bot = bot.getText().toString();
        st_top = top.getText().toString();
        x = Integer.parseInt(st_bot);
        y = Integer.parseInt(st_top);
        guess = (x+y)/2;
        tv_guess.setText(Integer.toString(guess));

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_bigger){

        st_bot = tv_guess.getText().toString();
        //st_top = top.getText().toString();
        guess = Integer.parseInt(st_bot);
        //y = Integer.parseInt(st_top);
        guess = (guess+y)/2;
        tv_guess.setText(Integer.toString(guess));

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_smaller){

        //st_bot = bot.getText().toString();
        st_top = tv_guess.getText().toString();
        //x = Integer.parseInt(st_bot);
        guess = Integer.parseInt(st_top);
        guess = (x+guess)/2;
        tv_guess.setText(Integer.toString(guess));
    }


}
```

I want to pass the variable x and y from the R.id.btn_guess statement so that I can use it in the other states with the value that have been assigned previously. But when I do that, x and y showed to be not have been initialized.

When I try to make this in Java compiler (not android), the variables can be used in other statements without reassigning it.

What is the workaround of this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve such a strange method? Is this really your question?

Answer (score 2):

According to your variable name, I *guess* you are implementing a game like "Guess Big or Small".

You *seems* want to assign `x` and `y` in branch `view.getId() == R.id.btn_guess`, then use them in other two branch. If this is really what you need, just pull the declaration of `x` and `y` to outside the function, which let them have a wider [variable scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), and keep them **after** `onClick` function ends at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Integer class and set it to null or you can initialize the ints to 0

Answer (score -1):

Try to make lik below and see what happens.

int guess=0, x=0, y=0;
String st_bot="", st_top="";